# Reading Parameter Value from DB in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

`I am trying to model a five stage supply chain simulation model in Anylogic. In this case, my source has two categories of havest namely Mango and Watermelon. Both harvest has varying demand. I need to set the source limit of each harvest according to their demand.

But whenever I am trying to do so, I am getting the following error " Cannot make a static reference to the non static field `MyFile.harvest`

Please note that MyFile is the name of my agent, and harvest is the column name that contains the data Mango and Watermelon. I will be attaching images for reference.

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Screenshot**
[image]

I am trying to limit the number of source for each harvest type, and see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try `agent.harvest`. And read up on "[the magic lightbulb](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/the-magic-light-bulb-by-benjamin-schumann/)" and how it helps you write code in code boxes.

(Then, start learning about the difference between agent types and agent instances)

Comment: Hello Mr. Benjamin, I will get back to you once I check. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello Benjamin, I think the problem is still there. I am adding images for your reference

Comment: The images still show the original situation. What do you mean by "I think the issue is there there"? Please be specific and feel free to adjust the question to the new situation (or open a new issue). Make it easy for us to help you :) Some tips on this here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow